# angular Clear icon inside input text

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to do something like this -> [Clear icon inside input text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258521/clear-icon-inside-input-text)

only in angular.js? I need it for my angular application and due to various private scopes I can't get it working with jQuery.

Comment: i have to add, that ng-show(!input=="") won't work, becouse inputs ng-model is always something(i use it as placeholder for older IE's).

Comment: you could take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468669/input-textbox-mimic-clear-text-x-button-just-like-select2-dropdown-component

Comment: i don't get the 'ng-model is always something' part

Comment: I think @frog means that the ngModel is never empty/null as it contains the place holder text whenever it's been emptied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using ng-model:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" ng-model="someTextField" />
    <button ng-click="someTextField = ''">x</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have ported the original jquery implementation to Angular JS.

[image]

[GitHub](https://github.com/aseemgautam/angular-input-clear-icon)

Comment: could you add license to the github

Answer (score 0):

I've created a directive through which you can clear inputs.

Check out the clear-icon directive at [GitHub](https://github.com/gangadharjannu/clear-icon)

Comment: could you add license to the github